# Diagnosing slow running app

Tags: process, exe, monitoring

I have a complicated .NET app that does text processing and it runs very slow. I want to capture all the processes it envokes so I could figure out what is causing it to run so slow. How can I determine which processes are running once I run this app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Windows Sysinternals' [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to monitor process activity.

Comment: I have never used that tool. Can it capture only the processes that started after I run the application?

Comment: Process Monitor captures all active processes, even if they started before running Process Monitor itself. You can also filter processes/threads on various conditions.